# R - How to run prcomp on imputed data from MICE package

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm uncertain on how I would run a PCA analysis via prcomp after running the mice function in R

If I run:

```
imp <- mice(Data, maxit = 20, m = 5)
```

It is my understanding that I now have 5 imputations of the data. In the JSS Buuren paper they then run:

```
fit <- with(imp, lm(chl ~ age + bmi))
pool(fit)
```

Which I understand that as running a linear regression with the 5 imputated data sets and then pooling the findings.

If I'm interested in instead running prcomp would I insert prcomp instead of lm in the with function?

Or would I possibly be better off extracting the 5 imputations via the complete function and averaging them and then inputing the averaged data into the prcomp function?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a minimal reproducible example.  Lines end where there are #.
`#reproducible example#
library(mice) #
x = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))  #create random data #
colnames(x) = paste0("x",LETTERS[1:10]) #
x[9:10,] = NA #add missingness #
x.mice = mice(x)  #make imputed data set #
prcomp(x.mice) #does not work #
x.prcomp = with(x.mice,prcomp(cbind(xA,xB,xC,xD,xE,xF,xG,xH,xI,xJ))) #
x.pooled = pool(x.prcomp) #does not work #`

Answer (score 0):

OK, the question is 7 years old, but it took me a while since I found a solution for the same problem: In the documentation of the miceadds package they give an example how to do this:

> prcomp(complete(x.mice))

Standard deviations (1, .., p=10):
[1] 1.674322e+00 1.480678e+00 1.139431e+00 1.057412e+00 9.096070e-01 5.692266e-01 4.525504e-01 2.262923e-01
[9] 3.655849e-02 2.080986e-17

Rotation (n x k) = (10 x 10):
PC1         PC2         PC3          PC4         PC5          PC6         PC7         PC8         PC9
xA  0.19646003  0.13756831 -0.33982392  0.069017366 -0.14163694  0.713314386  0.42817540 -0.02557612  0.26406627
xB  0.29362035 -0.05717179  0.18365741 -0.099420255  0.18354113 -0.325487631  0.14143764  0.25553536  0.79869087
xC -0.83458775  0.33975219 -0.14013481 -0.050463071  0.02468307 -0.004927709 -0.08765055 -0.07445376  0.38288139
xD -0.38346818 -0.72943808  0.06694925  0.219279568  0.29940640  0.103372672  0.38070191  0.14498401 -0.04125054
xE  0.07672487  0.33595433 -0.09365447  0.799073313  0.29771356 -0.094890402  0.07193397  0.03993132  0.01295771
xF  0.05436489 -0.37888215  0.07342579  0.309004299 -0.18074367  0.301450564 -0.66069343 -0.26573022  0.34512713
xG -0.01068478  0.19632445  0.47721165 -0.274347023  0.51557432  0.513112074 -0.15834345  0.16277618 -0.03726818
xH -0.13117602 -0.02992028  0.12868496 -0.003784248 -0.61694746  0.079079964  0.09069560  0.51198774  0.05424938
xI -0.05834026  0.12078943  0.70341638  0.169541787 -0.27858258 -0.014856917  0.36124512 -0.49151047  0.03382389
xJ  0.04515351 -0.14088749 -0.27096456 -0.310958714  0.10318544 -0.069965683  0.19636183 -0.55232842  0.13894432
PC10
xA  0.19909038
xB  0.06375321
xC  0.07341503
xD  0.01790238
xE -0.35970015
xF -0.05325361
xG -0.27620057
xH -0.55239981
xI  0.08610280
xJ -0.65537939

Comment: It is great you made the effort to answer an old question. It would be more helpful, though, if you formatted the output a bit so that we can actually read it like a table (or what format should it have?). You may want to see [this useful post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) about formatting and code blocks.